# unable to adjust xterm pointer color

Tags: xterm, mate-desktop

No matter what I set for pointerColor or pointerColorBackground, it remains black foreground and white background when hovering over xterm. I am using AWS Linux Workspace. All other settings are working for me that I have tried. Any global system settings are not stomping on these settings. The desktop environment is Mate. It seems like desktop manager is overtaking these color, but I am not certain how to check for that setting. I am more of a Fluxbox person but this is for work.

Thanks in advance!

```
Mate version is 1.24.1

xterm -version
X.Org 7.6.0(295)


xterm*loginShell: true
XTerm*selectToClipboard: true
XTerm*rightScrollBar: true
XTerm*foreground: black
XTerm*background: Cornsilk1
XTerm*cursorColor: green
XTerm*cursorBlink: true
XTerm*faceName: Monospace
XTerm*faceSize: 14
XTerm*renderFont: true
#XTerm*VT100.geometry: 176x68+50+0
XTerm*VT100.geometry: 80x50
XTerm*visualBell: true
XTerm*visualBellLine: true
Mwm*nodeco.clientDecoration: true
XTerm*charClass: 33:48,36-47:48,58-59:48,61:48,63-64:48,95:48,126:48
XTerm*on3Clicks: regex ([[:alpha:]]+://)?([[:alnum:]!#+,./=?@_~-]|(%[[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]))+
XTerm*SaveLines: 10000
XTerm*pointerShape: left_ptr
XTerm*pointerColor: green
XTerm*pointerColorBackground: white
```

Comment: `pointerColor` (and `pointerShape`) may be conflicting with cursor themes.

Comment: I tested this logic, and I am seeing no different results. I even cleared out .Xdefaults and loaded a blank .Xdefaults file and used command-line to spawn xterm with basics, and it was overridden, it seems.I used this: xterm -bg white -fg black -ms green

Same results. Pointer is default, along with standard colors. I may just give up, but it is frustrating that it appears this is only bit so far I've found that I can't alter, despite supporting documentation.